# Techniques of Intergration - Trig Intergrals Help

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^\frac{π}{4} \sin^4x \, \cos^2x \, dx= ? $$

[Problem 13. Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSrtT.png)

The problem is number 13 (in the picture). I'm confused on the second step because I don't see how they are getting $\frac{1}{2} \, (\sin(2x))^2$. Shouldn't it be the other way around, which is $\frac{1}{4} \, (1-\cos(2x))^2$. Since that is the half angle formula for $\sin^2(x)$ and there are $4$ powers of sine and only two powers of cosine ? Please help me, thank you.

Comment: $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$ and use $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), 
which is straightforward to learn, to express your math on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

$\int \sin^4 x\cos^2 x\ dx$

It looks like you want to say:

$\int (\frac 12(1-\cos 2x))^2(\frac 12(1+\cos 2x))\ dx$

Which is perfectly fine.  You can multiply that out, and you might have another simplifying step before you are done, but that is not such a big deal.

What has been done in this solution is to break up that first factor.

$\int (\sin^2 x)(\sin^2 x\cos^2 x)\ dx$
$\int (\sin^2 x)(\sin x\cos x)^2\ dx$
$\int (\sin^2 x)(\frac 12\sin 2x)^2\ dx$

And this is all done before applying the $\sin^2 x = \frac 12 (1-\cos 2x) , \cos^2 x = \frac 12 (1+\cos 2x)$ idnetities.

Comment: Okay I followed you down all the way to your 3rd step. I don't get that last step $$ \int (\sin^2 x)(\frac 12\sin 2x)^2\ dx $$ - What makes this simplify

Comment: $\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x$

Comment: Ahhh there we go! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EthanBarr If one of these answers resolved your question, please accept one (click the green checkmark) so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

There are different trig forms that can be obtained to integrate for this problem. In this view consider the following.
\begin{align}
\sin^{4}x \, \cos^{2}x &= (1-\cos^{2}x)^2 \, \cos^{2}x \\
&= \cos^{2}x - 2 \, \cos^{4}x + \cos^{6}x \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, (1 + \cos(2 x)) - 2 \, \frac{1}{8} \, (3 + 4 \, \cos(2 x) + \cos(4 x)) \\
& \hspace{10mm} + \frac{1}{32} \, (10 + 15 \, \cos(2 x) + 6 \, \cos(4 x) + \cos(6 x)) \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \, (2 - \cos(2 x) - 2 \, \cos(4 x) + \cos(6 x)).
\end{align}
With this then the integral becomes
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin^{4}x \, \cos^{2}x \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \, \int_{0}^{\pi/4} (2 - \cos(2 x) - 2 \, \cos(4 x) + \cos(6 x)) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \, \left[ 2 x - \frac{\sin(2 x)}{2} - \frac{\sin(4 x)}{4} + \frac{\sin(6 x)}{6} \right]_{0}^{\pi/4} \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \, \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \, \left( \frac{3 \pi - 4}{6} \right) = \frac{3 \pi - 4}{192}.
\end{align}